# Uploading image or a video to server as a raw data without encoding

Tags: iphone, objective-c, file-upload

Is it possible to upload an media(image & video ) directly to server without encoding which I am picking using UIImagepickerController, if so please suggest me how to do it.Please provide a sample for this.

Comment: you mean raw data? but why, this is really much more stuff to send?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of video upload you can send a file without encoding on the server 
Here is the code for that:

```
if ([type isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeVideo] ||  [type isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie])
{

NSURL *urlvideo = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

}
//IN urlVideo You get the path of media file(video files)           

NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/uploadVideo.php",appUrl];

NSURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:[str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setPostValue:self.gameID forKey:@"gameId"];//value for gameID Parameter

[request setFile:strurl forKey:@"uploadfile"]; //setFile method is used for upload video files

[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];

[request setDelegate:self];

[request startSynchronous];

NSLog(@"responseStatusCode %i",[request responseStatusCode]);

NSLog(@"responseStatusCode %@",[request responseString]);
```

I hope this might help you but please remember this does not work in case of image upload

Comment: k can u please post a sample for image upload if possible because i need to upload the image also in my app...